# What is the safest way to deliver an Application to novice Linux users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, rpm, deb

My customers are novice Linux users, and so am i.

When I gave them my App packaged with ansible, they saw ansible problems, when i gave them manual steps, they also screwed that up, now i have 3 last options, either a perl/bash script or a snappy/deb/rpm package or Linux containers, can anyone share their experience on the safest way to see less problems when installing my app (Written in C)?

Comment: Really depends on what the failure was. A correct dep/rpm should take of everything if you craft it right though. Correct install instructions should work too I guess - unless your app is a PITA to install :-)

Comment: does your App run on a server located at the clients location? or locally on the clients workstations?

Comment: How did you installed/test your app on a linux box ? Does your linux OS and your customer linux OS are same ? Put these info your question.

Comment: Either a native package or a container would be safe.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the nature of your application. Debs, rpms etc. are all fine but depend on which distro you're using.

If it's C application, it might make sense to make it a static binary. That way, you'll have to download a single file and just click on it to make it run. It will be big but it should work fine regardless of what else is there. Otherwise, you'll have to worry about dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented before it depends what you did to deploy the product.
In general, if you have dependencies (previous packages that you assume were already installed) or your installation is complex - use rpm or deb. 
However if you target multi-platform bare in mind you will have at least two releases (one rpm and one deb...)

If configuration or installation is easier you can just give them an install script.

If your application requires a specific environment with specific configuration/packages I'd consider containers although I never done that personally before.